# Are there any official maps of the Netherese Empire?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, forgotten-realms, maps

I have checked the AD&D books *Netheril: Empire of Magic* and *Lost Empires of Faerun*.

Are there any official maps of the Netheril empire?

Comment: Your related followup question: [Are there any official maps of the Seventon Alliance?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134731/are-there-any-official-maps-of-the-seventon-alliance)

Comment: @V2Blast they're definitely related but different in that the other question asks for specifically the seventon.

Comment: I know, just wanted to comment with a link so the two questions showed up as linked in the sidebar :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might this be of help ... ?

[image]

[The Grand History of the Realms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Grand_History_of_the_Realms) pg. 32

Only for reference, would have to find your own copy.

Comment: +1 This is exactly what i want though more clarity on the location of the seventon would be nice that wasn't a part of the question. Will wait to see if there are any better answers but this is likely to be the accepted answer.

Comment: @rpgstar If you are still around, you may want to accept this answer, since no others have come in in the last 2 years.

Comment: @WillemRenzema Yep. Must've missed it at the time. Done now.