# Are there any official maps of the Seventon Alliance?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, forgotten-realms, maps

I have checked the AD&D books *Netheril: Empire of Magic* and *Lost Empires of Faerun*, and the 3E book *Grand History of the Realms*.

Are there any official maps of the [Seventon Alliance](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Alliance_of_Seventon) and the locations of the seven towns?

Answer (score 5):

The location of the towns in the Seventon Alliance can actually be seen in the two poster maps ("Netheril at its Height: The Golden Age" and "Netheril at the Fall: 3520 NY") that come with the *Netheril: Empire of Magic* boxed set. They are to the north and east of what later turns into the Anauroch Desert on the eastern shore of the narrow sea.

Comment: Its more the location of the sevon towns than the region that the question is asking for.

Comment: @rpgstar: You mean the maps of the individual towns? The maps in the N:EoM boxed set show the locations of six towns individually. Do you want something like a zoomed in map?

Comment: Like where they are in the world. Not they're layout is was what I meant but I'll recheck the N:EoM map.

Comment: Just checked those maps and they give exactly what I wanted, I'm going to edit your answer to clarify your meaning.